# jqGrid add functionality is not working when data have the html tags(like <br/>)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

jqGrid add and edit functionality are not working when data have the html tags. like "br" "p" tags
if i give autoencode: true. then edit and add functionality are working fine. but it showing as one string.

for example:
Hi Ram "html br tag" How are you. My jqGrid should show as

Hi Ram 
 How are you

if i didn't give autoencode: true then add and edit functionality are not working.

**My code is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $("#divId").jqGrid({
    colNames:['mailSub','mailBody'],
     colModel: [

                    { name: 'mailSub', index: 'mailSub', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '150',
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',search:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}

                    },
                    { name: 'mailBody', index: 'mailBody', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '300',
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',search:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}

                    } 

              ],

        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        sortname: 'MessageKey',
        rowNum: 15,
        rowList: [15, 20, 25],
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: 340,
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: 'Messages',
        width: 660,
        url: "@Url.Content("url given")",
        editurl:"@Url.Content("EditUrl given")",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET'

    })
     jQuery("#divId").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit:true, add: true, del: false, search: true, refresh: true },
        { closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterEdit: true, left: 400, top: 300 },
        { closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterAdd: true, left: 450, top: 300, width: 520 },
        { closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, left: 450, top: 300 },
        {closeAfterSearch:true,closeAfterReset:true,left: 450, top: 300});
});
```

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jqGrid given property as

```
autoencode: true
```

above property is for encoding the data. Now in controller action method decoding the existed encoding data.

```
 String decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  `autoencode: true,` in your grid options

Comment: If i give autoencode:true then edit and add functionality working.. but it showing as string. for example  Hi Ram <br/> How are you. i need to break at after Hi Ram. but here showing as total one string.

Answer (score 0):

Set colmodel datatype = 'html'

Answer (score 0):

Add html tag in JQGrid column, you want to set the corresponding column's datatype as html.

datatype = 'html'